# Efficient LEFT JOIN on two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I am trying to join multiple table in SQL Server and keep the performance fast.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #tmpRecords 
(
    recordID INT NOT NULL, 
    filter1ID INT NOT NULL, 
    filter2ID INT NOT NULL, 
    filter3ID INT NULL, 
    filter4ID INT NULL, 
    filter5 VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_tempRecords 
ON #tmpRecords (filter1ID, filter2ID, filter3ID, filter4ID, filter5);

INSERT INTO #tmpRecords 
VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'test1'),
       (1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 'test1'),
       (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'test2'),
       (1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 'test2'),
       (2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'test1'),
       (2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 'test1'),
       (2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'test2'),
       (2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 'test2'),
       (3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'test1'),
       (4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'test1'),
       (5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'test1'),
       (6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'test1'),
       (7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'test1'),
       (8, 2, 1, 1, 1, 'test1'),
       (9, 3, 1, 1, 1, 'test1')

CREATE TABLE #tmpRecordsStock 
(
    filter1ID INT NULL, 
    filter2ID INT NULL, 
    filter3ID INT NULL, 
    filter4ID INT NULL, 
    filter5 VARCHAR(200) NULL, 
    StockQuantity INT NOT NULL
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_tempRecordsStock 
ON #tmpRecordsStock (filter1ID, filter2ID, filter3ID, filter4ID, filter5);

INSERT INTO #tmpRecordsStock 
VALUES 
(1,null,null,null,null,10),
(2,null,null,null,'test1',15),
(null,null,null,null,'test1',20),
(null,null,null,null,'test2',30),
(null,1,null,null,'test1',40),
(null,2,null,null,'test1',50)

SELECT
    T.recordID, T.filter1ID, T.filter2ID, T.filter3ID, T.filter4ID, 
    MAX(T.StockQuantity) AS StockQuantity
FROM
    (SELECT
         r.recordID, r.filter1ID, r.filter2ID, r.filter3ID,  
         r.filter4ID, r.filter5, MIN(s.StockQuantity) AS StockQuantity
     FROM
         #tmpRecords r
     LEFT JOIN
         #tmpRecordsStock s ON ((s.filter1ID IS NULL OR s.filter1ID = r.filter1ID)
                                AND (s.filter2ID IS NULL OR s.filter2ID = r.filter2ID)
                                AND (s.filter3ID IS NULL OR s.filter3ID = COALESCE(r.filter3ID, 0))
                                AND (s.filter4ID IS NULL OR s.filter4ID = COALESCE(r.filter4ID, 0))
                                AND (s.filter5 IS NULL OR s.filter5 = r.filter5))
     GROUP BY
         r.recordID, r.filter1ID, r.filter2ID, r.filter3ID, 
         r.filter4ID, r.filter5) T
GROUP BY
    T.recordID, T.filter1ID, T.filter2ID, T.filter3ID, T.filter4ID

DROP TABLE #tmpRecords
DROP TABLE #tmpRecordsStock
```

Trying to figure it out how to do this in a better way than above.

I already tried the indexes with real tables and also pass the `#tmpRecordsStock` instead of the `min` do a

```
SELECT TOP 1 StockQuantity 
FROM #tmpRecordsStock 
ORDER BY StockQuantity ASC
```

Comment: Looks, to me, like the problem is more the design. With columns like `filter1ID`, `filter2ID`, etc it seems it's denormalised.

Comment: The filters are only for purpose showing the problem on the left join. I have around 500mil records on first table and on second varies from 2000 to 5000 records and takes me about 5 minutes to run the final query.

Comment: So you actually have to `JOIN` on 5 completely different columns that may or may not be `NULL`? Still sounds like a design issue to me and you need some kind of surrogate key.

Comment: What does the execution plan show?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/REZBUGq.png something like this with the above example.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with derived tables, using the TOP keyword can improve performance.

```
    SELECT
    T.recordID, T.filter1ID, T.filter2ID, T.filter3ID, T.filter4ID, 
    MAX(T.StockQuantity) AS StockQuantity
FROM
    (SELECT TOP (2147483647)
         r.recordID, r.filter1ID, r.filter2ID, r.filter3ID,  
         r.filter4ID, r.filter5, MIN(s.StockQuantity) AS StockQuantity
     FROM
         #tmpRecords r
     LEFT JOIN
         #tmpRecordsStock s ON ((s.filter1ID IS NULL OR s.filter1ID = r.filter1ID)
                                AND (s.filter2ID IS NULL OR s.filter2ID = r.filter2ID)
                                AND (s.filter3ID IS NULL OR s.filter3ID = COALESCE(r.filter3ID, 0))
                                AND (s.filter4ID IS NULL OR s.filter4ID = COALESCE(r.filter4ID, 0))
                                AND (s.filter5 IS NULL OR s.filter5 = r.filter5))
     GROUP BY
         r.recordID, r.filter1ID, r.filter2ID, r.filter3ID, 
         r.filter4ID, r.filter5) T
GROUP BY
    T.recordID, T.filter1ID, T.filter2ID, T.filter3ID, T.filter4ID
```

Comment: didnt helped, the query execution plan was exactly the same.

Comment: I would try to break up the one derived table query into multiple derived queries.